# Из серии кэширования, работа с оперативкой

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно сделать такую вот тему:

При первом заходе на сайт данные о настройке сайта берутся из базы

Эти настройки одинаковы для всех посетителей, поэтому рыться в базу каждый раз и грузить ее нет особого смысла

Сохранять в файл можно, но это каждый раз нужно считывать файл крутя жесткий диск, а если он еще сильно занят прокруткой других файлов то это мало эффективно

Как можно сохранить данные в оперативке и брать их оттуда?

Answer (score 2):

если сервер свой, то можно сделать виртуальный диск в памяти. делается просто:

```
mkdir /mnt/myramdisk
mount -t tmpfs /mnt/myramdisk -o size=100m
```

`100m` -- размер диска.
`tmpfs` -- тип файловой системы

Comment: супер
и на нем то что я размещу будет хранится в оперативке?

Comment: да, но учтите, если вдруг сервер перезагрузится, то все данные будут потеряны. но впринципе как кэш вполне может подойти. ну и конечно же это под никсы. под винду можно [тут программы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) найти

Comment: Учтите, что если ОЗУ будет не хватать, то данные виртуального диска начнут **откачиваться** в swap (на реальный диск), а при обращении повторно читаться оттуда.

Разница с обычными файлами в том, что если система не загружена, то на диск ничего не пишется (в отличии от изменения обычных файлов). Но только вот  на относительно незагруженной системе эта запись (обычных файлов) на диск ничему не мешает (она производится как бы в фоне).

Answer (score 1):

использовать Alternative PHP Cache (APC) или использовать memcached

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал memcache+apc, чего и вам советую.

memcache для кэширования данных,

apc - для кэширования пхпшечки

Comment: вобще да, лучше их использовать. но раз вопрос был про оперативку, то... ;)

Comment: да собственно и в целом бы не помешало

это так была идея о том как разгрузить сервер простым способом

а вообще жаль что пхп с оперативкой не умеет работать